# dynamic Menu with sub menu in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to have a simple menu with a sub menu for each menu, i want my own style and don't want to use menu control in visual studio, any one can suggest how to have some thing like that?
and the important note is : i want to have a dynamic menu i mean i want to read menu items and sub menu items from database.

example :

```
menu-1
   sub-menu-1
   sub-menu-2
menu-2
   sub-menu-1
   sub-menu-2
```

maybe a table with this structure:

```
menuid       
menutitle    
menuhref     null able
parrentid    null able
```

i know i can use XML and ASP Menu control but i don't want to use XML and as you know ASP Menu control in generates some extra html codes that i don't want them, i want my own style, ul, li and classes or id for elements, i have my own style and structure and just want to know how to get menu items and sub menus and list them.
thanks for your help.

Comment: You can do this with "menu control in visual studio". Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: the menu control creates some extra html codes that i don't want them, i have my own style and html codes

Comment: ASPMenu renders very tight HTML, really no extras; also it is fully stylable with your own style and items can be dynamically created on the fly - it fits your use case pretty good. Alternative is to build HTML structure yourself manually using server-side HTML controls, but why invent the wheel?

Comment: ASPMenu needs XML or sitemap, and it renders ul or table with it's own extra codes i want it clean as you see in my solution that Rashed posted on a web site. any way thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think i can do like this, thanks [Rashed](http://cybarlab.com/author/rashed):
Query for creating table and some test data :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Menus](
       [MenuID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
       [ParentID] [bigint] NULL,
       [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
       [URL] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT[PK_Menus] PRIMARY KEYCLUSTERED
(
       [MenuID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
INSERT [dbo].[Menus]([MenuID], [ParentID], [Name], [URL]) VALUES (1, 0, N’Main Menu1′, N’Main Menu1′)
INSERT [dbo].[Menus]([MenuID], [ParentID], [Name], [URL]) VALUES (2, 0, N’Main Menu2′, N’Main Menu2′)
INSERT [dbo].[Menus]([MenuID], [ParentID], [Name], [URL]) VALUES (3, 0, N’Main Menu3′, N’Main Menu3′)
INSERT [dbo].[Menus]([MenuID], [ParentID], [Name], [URL]) VALUES (4, 1, N’Sub Menu 1.1′, N’Sub Menu 1.1′)
INSERT [dbo].[Menus]([MenuID], [ParentID], [Name], [URL]) VALUES (5, 1, N’Sub Menu 1.2′, N’Sub Menu 1.2′)
INSERT [dbo].[Menus]([MenuID], [ParentID], [Name], [URL]) VALUES (6, 2, N’Sub Menu 2.1′, N’Sub Menu 2.1′)
INSERT [dbo].[Menus]([MenuID], [ParentID], [Name], [URL]) VALUES (7, 2, N’Sub Menu 2.2′, N’Sub Menu 2.2′)
INSERT [dbo].[Menus]([MenuID], [ParentID], [Name], [URL]) VALUES (8, 3, N’Sub Menu 3.1′, N’Sub Menu 3.1′)
INSERT [dbo].[Menus]([MenuID], [ParentID], [Name], [URL]) VALUES (9, 3, N’Sub Menu 3.2′, N’Sub Menu 3.2′)
INSERT [dbo].[Menus]([MenuID], [ParentID], [Name], [URL]) VALUES (10, 3, N’Sub Menu 3.2′, N’Sub Menu 3.3′)
```

and in page load :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgse)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable oDataTable = newDataTable();
            oDataTable = SelectDataTable(“SELECT  MenuID, ParentID, Name, URL FROM     Menus”);
            DataRow[] drParentMenu = oDataTable.Select(“ParentID = 0″);
            var oStringBuilder = newStringBuilder();
            string MenuList = GenerateMenu(drParentMenu, oDataTable, oStringBuilder);
            Literal1.Text = MenuList;
        }
    }
```

GetConnectionStrings

```
public string GetConnectionStrings()
{
stringConStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ConnectionString;
returnConStr;
}
```

SelectDataTable

```
public  DataTable SelectDataTable(String Sql)
{
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlConnection oSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionStrings());

try
{
oSqlConnection.Open();
SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(Sql, GetConnectionStrings());
sqlda.Fill(dt);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
throw new Exception(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
oSqlConnection.Close();
oSqlConnection.Dispose();
}

return dt;
}
```

GenerateMenu

```
private string GenerateMenu(DataRow[] drParentMenu, DataTable oDataTable, StringBuilder oStringBuilder)
{
oStringBuilder.AppendLine(“<ul>”);if (drParentMenu.Length > 0)
{
foreach (DataRow dr in drParentMenu)
{
string MenuURL = dr["URL"].ToString();
string MenuName = dr["Name"].ToString();
string line = String.Format(@”<li ><a href=”"{0}”">{1}</a>”, MenuURL, MenuName);
oStringBuilder.Append(line);
string MenuID = dr["MenuID"].ToString();
string ParentID = dr["ParentID"].ToString();
DataRow[] subMenu = oDataTable.Select(String.Format(“ParentID = {0}”, MenuID));
if (subMenu.Length > 0 && !MenuID.Equals(ParentID))
{
var subMenuBuilder = new StringBuilder();
oStringBuilder.Append(GenerateMenu(subMenu, oDataTable, subMenuBuilder));
}
oStringBuilder.Append(“</li>”);

}
}
oStringBuilder.Append(“</ul>”);
return oStringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: While searching google I found this article: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Multilevel-Dynamic-CSS3-Dropdown-Menu-in-asp-net it helped me a lot.